# Open new terminal with environment specified by source command

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables, source, xfce4-terminal

I want to run a command that opens a terminal and sources into it a set of variables.

How can I do this? I'm using xfce4-terminal. It has a command-line arg "--command", to execute commands upon opening the terminal. But that arg doesn't appear to allow execution of the source command.

## For example:

### use terminal's --command flag to open it with sourced environment vars

```
xfce4-terminal \
--command 'source somefile' \
--hold &
```

But it just gives an error: failed to execute child process 'source': no such file or directory.

*That is what you would try naturally after reading the xfce4-terminal's sparse manpage.*

## How about specifically invoking bash within the new terminal to source the file?

```
xfce4-terminal \
--command 'bash -c "source somefile \
--hold &
```

That executes the source command, but as soon as it is finished the terminal exits.

*You might try that after searching the forums and finding it written that one must call bash to run the bash command source. (What is that? Start a terminal with a bash instance to call another bash to run the command)*

## call bash within bash, within bash, within terminal, to run the command

```
xfce4-terminal \
--command 'bash -c "source somefile; bash"' \
--hold &
```

That opens a terminal and keeps it open, but without the sourced environment.

*Seems silly, but that's something else you might try after searching the forums.*

## use bash to call bash with sourced environment

```
xfce4-terminal \
--command 'bash -c "bash -c \"source somefile; some_command\""' \
--hold &
```

That sources the new env in a new terminal, but it just closes again as soon as the source cmd has finished executing. *(Just some guesswork)*

## create a script called source_somefile which invokes bash and runs 'source somefile'

```
xfce4-terminal \
--command 'source_somefile' \
--hold &
```

No. The terminal closes again as soon as the source cmd has finished executing.

Though you can't be blamed for thinking that would surely work: putting the source cmd in a script and running that using the terminal with the --command flag, so that the --hold flag might also be used to stop the terminal exiting when the source command has finished executing?

How about, running the script as: bash -c 'source somefile'?

No: terminal closes again as soon as the source cmd has finished executing.

So how *can* this be done, short of printing off the xfce4-terminal manpage and ritually burning it over a blood sacrifice under a harvest moon? And then howling... howling...

Answer (score 0):

You just source first and open the terminal after (I am using the portable `.` instead of the bash-specific `source`):

```
. source_somefile && xfce4-terminal
```

The terminal will inherit the environment it was sourced from. For example, if I have this:

```
$ cat /home/terdon/file
export my_var="foo"
```

And then make an alias like this:

```
alias my_profile='. /home/terdon/file && xfce4-terminal'
```

I can then run the alias which will open a new terminal in which `echo $my_var` will print `foo`. Note that the variables will need to be `export`ed for this, and you should use the full path to the file you are sourcing.

[image: screenshot showing this in action]

Comment: Bizarrely perhaps, this did not work. For example: `echo "export a=\"eh?\"" > somefile && . somefile && xfce4-terminal`, left `a` set as expected in the controlling terminal but empty in the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/10/msg00049.html) a possible solution. So maybe using `--disable-server` flag works in the end...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).